# Java 7 SSL connection to SQL Server 2014 from Tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, database, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 with Java 7 via JDBC driver and the error that the app throws is :

> The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed."

My code is:

```
driver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
url ="jdbc:sqlserver://Ip:port;databasename=xxx";
user = "xxx";
pass = "xxx";
Class.forName(driver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

I downloaded the ODBC driver package from [MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=11774) and have tried using each of the following in turn: `sqljdbc.jar`, `sqljdbc4.jar`, `sqljdbc41.jar`, and `sqljdbc42.jar`, but I got the same error each time.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you provided specifying SSL.

Comment: What PORT are you using?

Comment: 5081 is the port what i using to connect.

Comment: If by "used all of [them]" you mean that you put all four JAR files in your CLASSPATH/Build_Path then try removing three of them and just leaving `sqljdbc4.jar`. That one works for me when connecting to a SQL Server instance that requires an SSL connection.

Comment: Not , I just used one by one , and no one working.

Comment: @IvanFontalvo - Try creating a simple Java console application to connect to the SQL Server with `sqljdbc4.jar`. If that fails then your problem is more fundamental (e.g., SQL Server settings, network configuration, etc.). If it succeeds, then you'll need to dig deeper into the details of your Tomcat configuration. (Also, remember to include @UserName when replying to a comment.)

Comment: I created a simple jar to connect , and put in the server that have acces to the bd , and after run the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the issue using [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) as driver manager , my code now is :

```
driver ="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver;
url ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://Ip:port;databasename=xxx";
user = "xxx";
pass = "xxx";
Class.forName(driver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

and i added the lib jtds1.5.1 in my classpath.

Comment: There is no jtds1.5.1 binary at the link you provided.

Comment: Surprisingly JTDS 1.3 (last stable version) also works to resolve this error.